# 64 bit portability issues

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, size-t

All this originated from me poking at a compiler warning message (C4267) when attempting the following line:

```
const unsigned int nSize = m_vecSomeVec.size();
```

`size()` returns a size_t which although typedef'd to unsigned int, is not actually a unsigned int. This I believe have to do with 64 bit portability issues, however can someone explain it a bit better for me? ( I don't just want to disable 64bit warnings.)

Comment: SO why are you not using size_t for nSize? C++ is very type sensitive/strict (by design). So always use the correct type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. `std::size_t` for example has a minimal required size. But there is no upper limit. To avoid these kind of situations, always use the proper typedef:

```
const std::vector<T>::size_type nSize = m_vecSomeVec.size();
```

You will be always on the safe side then.

Comment: True - size_t might not be big enough for vector<bool>.

Answer (score 3):

When compiling for a 64-bit platform, `size_t` will be a 64-bit type. Because of this, Visual Studio gives warnings about assigning `size_t`s to `int`s when 'Detect 64-bit Portability Issues' is enabled.

Visual C++ gets this information about `size_t` through the `__w64` token, e.g. `__w64 unsigned int`.

Refer the below link for more on 64 bit porting issues..
http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0065/

Answer (score 2):

If `size_t` is typedef:ed to `unsigned int`, then of course it is an `unsigned int`, on your particular platform. But it is abstracted so that you cannot depend on it *always* being an `unsigned int`, it might be larger on some other platform.

Probably it has not been made larger since it would cost too much to do so, and e.g. vectors with more than 2^32 items in them are not very common.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the compiler, `int` may be 32-bits in 64-bit land.